# SybaseASE and C#

Tags: c#, .net, sybase

I am trying to create a windows application in C#.net. In which I am trying to export some records of a table like(select * from table_name where value ='1234'). I want to export this data to a text file on my system. I am using reader to do this.
But, with reader I am unable to get column names to the output file. I need to get the selected records along with table structure to the output file.
And please suggest if there is any better way(other then the reader) to store the resultset of a sybase query in C#.

Please let me know if anything needs to be add.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the code that is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

As you are new here, I will give you this for free. However in future, please do a little more research into your question before posting. I, as most people here, have a full time tech job, and we donate our time to the community for free.

In this particular case, msdn AND visual studio has more than enough documentation required for you to complete your task.

I assume you as using the `IDbReader` interface.

You should be able to use the auto-complete function of Visual Studio to explore the implemented functions on `IDbReader` and find `IDbReader.GetName(int)` yourself. Failing that there is also the `object explorer` AND msdn's documentation pages (which I have YET to find anything close to on other frameworks).

Please next time spend a small amount of time trying to find the solution yourself before you post here. We only ask that the [Stackoverflow guidelines on posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

```
using(IDbConnection connection = new SybaseAseConnection()) //(I honestly can't remember the name)
{
    connection.Open();
    IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SQL";
    using(IDbReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         List<string> fieldNames = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                                   .Select(i => reader.GetName(i)).ToList(); 
    }
}
```